# I need to display a score in my game that can update as the player gains score

Tags: java, scoring

I've been trying to get this to work for a long time and I'm stuck. I've got a scoring system that "works" (it has a score that will increase when the player collects a coin) But I cannot for the life of me get it to display the score in the top left of the screen (or get it to display at all). I've tried using a JLabel like so:

```
JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");
public void someoneScored()
{
Score++;
scoreLabel.setBounds(5, 5, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + Score);
}
```

Comment: why dont g.drawString(Score, x ,y);?

Comment: add your JLabel to your container that is displaying currently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `label` inside you `panel` , like this example :

```
JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");
add(scoreLabel);/// assuming you have Jpanel class

public void someoneScored()
{
  Score++;
  scoreLabel.setBounds(5, 5, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + Score);
}
```